# Исключить из списка полных путей все которые подходят одному из регулярных выражений

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Использую модуль `find` получаю список всех файлов по заданному пути, необходимо исключить из него все которые подходят одному из регулярных выражений.

Задача была бы тривиальной если в самом модуле `find` параметры `patterns` и `excludes` применялись к полному пути найденного файла, а не только к его имени.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9a51dff0b17f01bcb280a438ecfe785e5fda4541/lib/ansible/modules/files/find.py#L420

```
- name: get list of files
  find:
     paths: "/home/vagrant"
     patterns: ".*"
     excludes:
        - ".*ansible.*"
        - ".*ssh.*"
     file_type: Any
     recurse: True
     use_regexp: True
  reguster: find_list
```

Список исключений

```
- name: excludes
  set_facts:
     find_excludes:
        - ".*ansible.*"
        - ".*ssh.*"
```

Реализация в модуле `find` очень простая, но она применяется не к абсолютному пути:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9a51dff0b17f01bcb280a438ecfe785e5fda4541/lib/ansible/modules/files/find.py#L236

```
        elif patterns and excludes:
            for p in patterns:
                r = re.compile(p)
                if r.match(f):
                    for e in excludes:
                        r = re.compile(e)
                        if r.match(f):
                            return False
                    return True
```

Думал в сторону **jinja2** фильтра `map('regex_search', find_excludes)|list`

Comment: проблема в том, что нужно отсортировать список путей, но они не абсолютные? проблема в том, чтобы получить исходные пути, или как то отсортировать те, что есть?

Comment: @finally нужно вернусь списком пути, где не содержатся любой из патернов. Патерн применяется ко ВСЕМУ пути, a не какой либо из его частей (корень, папка, файл) `/полный/путь/до/какого/либо/файла.здесь`

Изначальная задача

очистить каталог `/home/vagrant` от всего кроме `/home/vagrant/.ssh/` и `/home/vagrant/.ansible/`

Comment: для прояснения - `.ssh/` и `.ansible/` это ведь расширения файлов?

Comment: @finally это пути `.ssh/` это директория находящаяся в `/home/USER`, в моем случае `/home/vagrant/.ssh/`. В shell  это решается в одну строку 2мя командами `find /home/vagrant | grep -v "\.ansible\|\.ssh"`, но я ищу элегантный модуль или фильтра. Гугл уже прочитал до 20й вкладки :)

Comment: если вам нужна сама регулярка - то `/home/vagrant/(\.ansible|\.ssh).*` оставит только пути до каталогов `/home/vagrant/.ssh/`, `/home/vagrant/.ansible/` и любые подкаталоги после. или нужен сам парсер?)